# Power supply overload protection work around

Tags: power-supply, power, filter

I have the following power supply [here](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/RPMB-2.0.pdf)

I need to switch on a contactor that uses around 3.2A inrush current for around 20ms (I cannot find the datasheet for this).

Now the power supply breaks down the output voltage around 3.1A. So at 3.1A, the output voltage of the power supply is 0V, however, the current stills remain. I tested this using a DC Load tester.

I do not have enough time to buy another power supply. So I was thinking of just using a simple LC filter that is located on the contactor in order to provide this extra bit to turn the contactor on before the power supply overload protection kicks in. My question is how do I calculate the values for L and C?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXvrJ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

][1](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/RPMB-2.0.pdf).

Comment: The coil of a relay is primarily resistive and inductive. Thus, one would expect that it would consume _less_ current initially, and _more_ current when it settles. (The terminal voltage divided by the DC resistance.) Are you sure you will get an inrush current for 20 mSec that then reduces?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The current required to hold a contactor in the on state is often less than what is required to initially close it.  For that reason many contactors have a built in "economizer" circuit on the coil that reduces the current after a short time.  Here is one example.  https://www.gigavac.com/sites/default/files/application-notes/AN-002-Two-Coil-Economizer-Principles.pdf

Comment: @user4574 Good to know.

Comment: Couldn't you throw some power diodes or regulator in series to lower the voltage and hopefully the current enough to avoid the threshold?

Comment: Don't forget that freewheeling diode should be rated to maximum working current of the coil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to switch on a contactor that uses around 3.2A inrush current for around 20ms...

> ...the power supply breaks down the output voltage around 3.1A

> ... at 3.1A, the output voltage of the power supply is 0V, however, the current stills remain.

This answer will not address whether there are more appropriate solutions to providing your needed inrush current than the one you seem to be asking for. Nor will it address whether using a capacitor and/or inductor is appropriate or needed at all. Rather, it will address two questions.

**If I use a circuit similar to the one in my question, what should the component values be?**

**Should the inductor be used or just the capacitor alone?**

I am making the following assumptions

1. Your power supply (PSU) is of the CVCC (constant voltage-constant current) type. That is, if the load draws less than the set current, then the PSU will supply a constant voltage at the set voltage value. If output voltage is less than the set voltage, then the PSU will supply a constant current at the set current value.
2. When you switch on the power to the load, the specified inrush current must be available immediately, or close to it, rather than after some non-trivial delay.
3. The load that requires the specified inrush current can be modeled either as

- a constant current sink with a compliance voltage, or
- a simple resistive load

Note that these assumptions may not apply to your actual situation. Particularly worth mention is that the circuitry necessary to supply the surplus current depends on the character of the load. Do not expect a circuit that works for one sort of load to work correctly for another sort of load. Neither load model discussed in this answer may be even close to accurately modeling the coil of your relay, which is likely to be *inductive*.

### **No Inductor Needed or Useful with These Loads**

For a resistive or constant current sink load, no inductor is needed between the capacitor and the PSU in the circuit, nor is one beneficial to the circuit. Such an inductor would be problematic. Current would flow through the inductor when capacitor was charging, but there would likely be no current when the switch is turned on. When the switch is in fact turned on, the inductor would *impede* the flow of current to the load -- the opposite of what is desired. There would be a finite rise-time for the current, which would violate the assumption:

> 2. When you switch on the power to the load, the specified inrush current must be available immediately, or close to it, rather than after some non-trivial delay.

### **Some CircuitLab Models Used**

**A CVCC PSU model in CircuitLab**

For the purposes of this answer, we will model your CVCC PSU with the following circuit elements:

[image]

I have implemented Constant Voltage - Constant Current PSU in a rather peculiar way, because that way seems to be the easiest way in CircuitLab.

When that PSU is connected to a variable, resistive load, if the output current is less than 3.1 A, then the output voltage is 12 V. If the output voltage is less than 12 V, then the output current is 3.1 A.

[image]
[image]

**A Constant Current Sink with Compliance Voltage Model in CircuitLab**

[image]
[image]

Again, the current sink design may appear odd, but it was chosen for it's simplicity in CircuitLab.

---

### **Supplying Extra Current to a Constant Current Sink**

This circuit is powered by a 3.1A PSU. However, it will supply 100 mA extra current for at least 20 mSec to a 3.2A constant current sink. We will be using a single capacitor for the job. The capacitor needs to charge before power is applied to the load. For this reason, the capacitor is placed between the PSU and a switch.

The total charge that the capacitor needs to carry is the extra current times the time this current is needed.

$$Q_{extra}=I_{extra}T_{extra}$$

or in this case:

\$Q_{extra} = 100 mA * 20 mSec = 2000 uC = 2 mC\$ (2 milli-coulombs)

At this point we must choose the allowable voltage sag on the output. It is the declining output voltage which enables the capacitor to deliver extra current to the load. The output voltage cannot be allowed to sag below compliance voltage of the constant current sink load. Aside from that limit, the lower the voltage is allowed to sag, the smaller the capacitor which is needed.

The capacitance needed will be the extra charge needed divided by the allowable voltage sag.

$$C_{min} = Q_{extra}/V_{sag(max)}$$

We will arbitrarily set the maximum voltage sag at 1V. In this case

\$C_{min} = 2 mC / 1 V = 2 mF = 2000 uF\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAg1jm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the current supplied by the PSU (blue), and the current through the load (orange).
[image]

And here is the output voltage
[image]

The simulator for this circuit is set to close the switch at time T=20 mSec. This circuit draws 3.1 A for about 7.8 mSec while the capacitor charges. The current then falls to 0. At chart time T=20 mSec, the switch is closed, and load draws 3.2 A while the PSU only supplies 3.1 A. The sagging voltage across the capacitor causes the capacitor to supply the remaining 100 mA. After 20 mSec more (chart time T=40 mSec), the voltage falls by 1V to 11V. If the load continues to draw 3.2 A, that current will continue to be provided and the output voltage will continue to drop until the current sink compliance voltage is reached.

### **Supplying Extra Current to a Resistive Load**

A significant difference between a resistive load and the constant current sink that was discussed earlier is that with a resistive load, the voltage falls exponentially, rather than linearly. The exponential rate of decay depends on both the capacitor and the load resistance, as well as the constant current supplied by the PSU.

In practice, the load resistance is fixed. However, to make this example comparable with the previous one, we want it to be the case that 20 mSec after power is applied to the load, the current is 3.2 A (the same as the current draw of the constant current sink load). Further, we want the same voltage sag 20 mSec after power is applied to the load, or 11 V. The resistance of the load thus needs to be \$11 V / 3.2 A = 3.4375 \Omega \approx 3.44 \Omega \$.

The formula we use for calculating the required capacitance for the resistive load is

$$C = -\frac{T}{R \ln \left(1 - \frac{V_{sag}}{V_{PSU} - I_{PSU}R_{LOAD}}\right)}$$

In our case, this works out to be

$$C = -\frac{20 mSec}{3.44\Omega \ln \left(1 - \frac{1 V}{12 V - 3.1 A \cdot 3.44 \Omega}\right)} = 4.26 mF$$

This is over twice the capacitance needed compared to the case of a constant current sink load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frK9zu.png)</sup>

The simulator for this circuit is set to close the switch at time T=40 mSec.

Here is the current supplied by the PSU (blue), and the current seen by the load (orange).

[image]

And here is the voltage seen at the PSU.

[image]

It takes approximately 17 mSec to initially charge up the capacitor before the switch is closed (at 40 mSec).

When the switch closes, the initial current through the load is 3.49 A. This then decays exponentially to 3.2 A at 20 mSec after the switch closes. If the load remains constant, the current will continue to exponentially decay until with a limit of 3.1 A and a limiting voltage of 10.66 V.

Comment: So the inductor is added to prevent the cap from blowing due to the inrush current. How would I spec the inductor?

Comment: I forgot to add after around 20ms, the current the contactor draws is around 0.19A

Comment: No problem, will also be back tomorrow.

Comment: Just checking on how to size an inductor that is in parallel with the cap and the contactor on order to limit the inrush into the capacitor

Comment: "When the switch is in fact turned on, the inductor would impede the flow of current to the load -- the opposite of what is desired." But if the inductor is placed between the cap and PSU like a LC filter then it will not impede current from going to the load as the inductor is seen as an high impedance compared to the load, isn't it? Because on startup of the circuit the cap is seen as a short circuit from the PSU so we need to limit the inrush.

Comment: 1. Inductors "resist" changes in current. Since no current is flowing through the inductor when the switch is closed, it will "resist" a new flow of current. 2. My understanding is that the PSU has current limiting, so the current used to charge the capacitor is limited by the PSU

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'd actually want to do this... adding a C in parallel to the relay coil will form a [resonant tank](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=resonant+tank) circuit. When power is removed, the the 3.1A stored in the relay will start oscillating against the capacitor at likely several hundred volts!

Instead, omit the L and add a switch after the cap - let the power supply charge the cap, then throw the switch.  The cap should provide enough initial current boost to close the relay before current-limiting begins.  Then open that switch to release the relay.

Note that, opening this switch will cause the relay to dump all of it's stored current as a spark across the switch.  Could place a [freewheeling diode](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=freewheeling+diode) across the relay coil if desired.

Comment: OH I forgot to add a flyback diode on the relay.

Comment: I do not want to add a switch. this needs to happen without human intervention

Comment: @JoeyB "switch" does not imply a manual switch requiring human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ll need a representative SPICE model for the contractor coil.

Measure the inductance and series resistance of the contractor coil – using an LCR meter, as it’ll do both at once.

Then simulate this circuit being switched on using SPICE; CircuitLab will work fine – just make sure you add a time-delay switch so you capture the transient.

Then get a current probe or current sensor, hook it up to an oscilloscope, capture the inrush current waveform when powering from another power supply, and compare the transient to the one you got in SPICE. The magnetization-related inrush may need to be modeled by an RC circuit in parallel to the coil, so that you get a similarly looking peak. The R should be as small as possible while manipulating the C for good match.

Now that you have a suitable model, you can do spice experiments to emulate the solutions you have in mind.

Comment: My solution looks to be in line with the topology of a buck converter, so the initial calculations for L and C can be calculated using the equations for a buck converter?